# getting the search page result, login with jwt authentication (python)

Tags: python, parsing, authentication, jwt

I am trying to get the html page to parse. The site itself has login form. I am using the following code to get through the login form:

```
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "referer":"https://somesite/"
    }

payload = {
        "email": us,
        "password": ps,
        "web": "true"
    }

session_requests = requests.session()
response = session_requests.post(
        site,
        data = json.dumps(payload),
        headers = headers
    )

result = response
resultContent = response.content
resultCookies = response.cookies

resultContentJson = json.loads(resultContent)
resultJwtToken = resultContentJson['jwtToken']
```

That works just fine, I am able to get 200 OK status and jwtToken.

NOW. When I actually trying to get the page (search result) the site returns to me '401 - not authorized'..  So, the question is 'what am I am doing wrong?'. Any suggestion/hint/idea is appreciated!

here is the request that gets 401 response:

```
siteSearch = "somesite/filters/search"
    headersSearch = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "referer":"https://somesite",
        "origin":"https://somesite",        
        "authorization":"Bearer {}".format(resultJwtToken),
        "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36"
    }

payloadSearch = {
        "userId":50432,
        "filters" : [],        
        "savedSearchIds":[],
        "size":24
    }
responseSearch = session_requests.post(
        siteSearch,
        data = json.dumps(payloadSearch),
        headers = headers
    )

searchResult = response;
```

looking at the postman and chrome developer tools and seems to me I am sending the identical request as the actual browser (works via browser).. but nope - 401 response.

May be it has something to do with the cookies? The first login response returns bunch of cookies as well, but I thought the session_requests takes care about it?

in any way, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

typo..  in responseSearch I used for the headers the headers defined in the initial login. should be headers = headersSearch.  All the rest works as expected. Thanks!